# slider not seen in js fiddle even though all files are included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am trying to implement the slider in fiddle..
i included all the files but i am not able to see the output...
can you tell me the reason...
providing my code below in the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/xDTh6/

http://www.slidesjs.com/#examples

```
<img src="img/example-slide-1.jpg" alt="Photo by: Missy S Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/listenmissy/5087404401/">
            <img src="img/example-slide-2.jpg" alt="Photo by: Daniel Parks Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/parksdh/5227623068/">
            <img src="img/example-slide-3.jpg" alt="Photo by: Mike Ranweiler Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/27874907@N04/4833059991/">
            <img src="img/example-slide-4.jpg" alt="Photo by: Stuart SeegerLink: http://www.flickr.com/photos/stuseeger/97577796/">
```

<

Comment: Your jsFiddle is very wrong.

Comment: View your error console.

Answer (score 1):

You must understand how JSFiddle works.

1. JSFiddle creates its own `<HTML>`, `<BODY>` and `<HEAD>` portions.
2. All that we enter in `HTML` section on top-left quadrant is what goes inside the `<BODY>` tag.
3. Any external javascript library or CSS that we need to include should be included via `External Resources` option on the left.
4. Basically only your minimal client HTML, JavaScript and CSS must go in any of the quadrants.

Here I fixed the JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/xDTh6/1/

If you have confusions about JSFiddle in general, then you can go through [its documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

If you view your console errors, all of the files aren't pulling because they're trying to be pulled relatively. If you have them uploaded somewhere, link them absolutely and you should mostly be good.